# Why the strings sticks out from the Bubble window?

Tags: html, css

Strings has to go to next line if it's long. How can I do this?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yu6dD/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="chat">

<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
               <th>Body</th>
     </tr>



    <tr id="comment_617">
            <td><div class="bubble me"><span class="text-error">01-10 03:29</span>：Person A<br>
            bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
            <form action="/shop/walmart/posts/617" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post"><div><input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden"><input data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-disable-with="deleting..." value="destroy" type="submit"><input name="authenticity_token" value="aoLKQnl4M2SWVlOrXGR+qIMLSeY5m1tKiC/PSnYQjmw=" type="hidden"></div></form>
            </div></td>
    </tr>




    <tr id="comment_615">
            <td><div class="bubble me"><span class="text-error">01-10 03:25</span>：Person A<br>
            bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
            <form action="/shop/walmart/posts/615" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post"><div><input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden"><input data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-disable-with="deleting..." value="destroy" type="submit"><input name="authenticity_token" value="aoLKQnl4M2SWVlOrXGR+qIMLSeY5m1tKiC/PSnYQjmw=" type="hidden"></div></form>
            </div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

 <div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chat {
    width: 400px;
}

.bubble{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.bubble::before {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    transform:             rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    width:  20px;
}

.me {
    float: left;   
    margin: 5px 45px 5px 5px;
    width: 200px;       
}

.me::before {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    left: -9px;           
}

.you {
    float: left;    
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    width: 200px;         
}

.you::before {
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    right: -9px;    
}
```

Comment: Why is question being marked down? The guy has a problem, needed help, he posted code. What's wrong?? +1

Comment: @Bryan Agree. Sometimes a down-vote requires no explanation. IMO a down-vote on this post does.

Comment: @KevinBoucher - We can't lose objectivity. Just because something may come as second nature to some, does not make another's question superfluous. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your `.bubble` class:

```
  word-break: break-all;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-break

Comment: Thanks!! so quick. I will vote it up in 15mins:) Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for being a positive force and answering a legitimate quesiton.