# How can I make width 100% max ? when I'm looking with both PC and iPhone?

Tags: html, css

There is a table in my layout. I'm also using bootstrap's responsive design.
I want to know how to expand its width depending on the devices that I'm looking with.

For example, with my PC, my web site is usually shown with about 1200px width.
With my iPhone, my web site is usually shown with its resolution, which is about 640px.

I want to expand the bubble's width as much as possible(I mean 100% width)
Bubble's width should be flexible.  Shrinking window's width should make it resized automatically.

How can I?

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/8ASj4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="chat">

<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
               <th>Body</th>
     </tr>



    <tr id="comment_617">
            <td><div class="bubble me"><span class="text-error">01-10 03:29</span>：Person A<br>
            bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
            <form action="/shop/walmart/posts/617" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post"><div><input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden"><input data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-disable-with="deleting..." value="destroy" type="submit"><input name="authenticity_token" value="aoLKQnl4M2SWVlOrXGR+qIMLSeY5m1tKiC/PSnYQjmw=" type="hidden"></div></form>
            </div></td>
    </tr>




    <tr id="comment_615">
            <td><div class="bubble me"><span class="text-error">01-10 03:25</span>：Person A<br>
            bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
            <form action="/shop/walmart/posts/615" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post"><div><input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden"><input data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-disable-with="deleting..." value="destroy" type="submit"><input name="authenticity_token" value="aoLKQnl4M2SWVlOrXGR+qIMLSeY5m1tKiC/PSnYQjmw=" type="hidden"></div></form>
            </div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

 <div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chat {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
}

.bubble{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.bubble::before {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    transform:             rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    width:  20px;
}

.me {
    float: left;   
    margin: 5px 45px 5px 5px;
    min-width: 250px; 
    width: 100%;      
}

.me::before {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    left: -9px;           
}

.you {
    float: left;    
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    min-width: 250px;
    width: 100%;          
}

.you::before {
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    right: -9px;    
}
```

Comment: Tables fell out of use for layouts 10 years ago. Use DIVs instead.

Comment: @Diodeus Are you serious? could you please show me how?

Comment: Tables have a default display of `table`, which basically means "be only as wide as necessary to contain all of my children".

Comment: Yes, seriously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: @Diodeus http://jsfiddle.net/SAKWb/  please shrink down the width and see it that content is sticking out of fluid. This is my issue

Answer (score 1):

Just remove all of the table related tags (table/td/tr/etc.)

```
<div class="chat">

<div class="bubble me"><span class="text-error">01-10 03:29</span>：Person A<br>
            bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
            <form action="/shop/walmart/posts/617" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post"><div><input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden"><input data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-disable-with="deleting..." value="destroy" type="submit"><input name="authenticity_token" value="aoLKQnl4M2SWVlOrXGR+qIMLSeY5m1tKiC/PSnYQjmw=" type="hidden"></div></form>
            </div>

              <div class="bubble me"><span class="text-error">01-10 03:25</span>：Person A<br>
            bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
            <form action="/shop/walmart/posts/615" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post"><div><input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden"><input data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-disable-with="deleting..." value="destroy" type="submit"><input name="authenticity_token" value="aoLKQnl4M2SWVlOrXGR+qIMLSeY5m1tKiC/PSnYQjmw=" type="hidden"></div></form>
            </div>

 <div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ASj4/2/

Comment: Thanks for answer. But contents sticks out from fluid when it's showing with bootstrap's responsive design :( Any idea?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SAKWb/  please shrink down the width and see it that content is sticking out of fluid. This is my issue

Comment: Wasn't that solved in your previous question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264958/why-the-strings-sticks-out-from-the-bubble-window

Comment: I was asking about the string was sticking out of bubble, now bubble itself is sticking out from fluid when I shrink down the window's width. Please try the js fiddle link! It's how shown in iPhone:(

Comment: You mean because of the `min-width: 300px` on your `.chat` element?

Comment: There's also a `min-width: 250px` on the `.me` and `.you` elements.

Comment: I removed it but it won't help:(